# Message During Gem Install - SocketError: nodename nor servname provided

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Anytime I install a gem, I see following warnings:

```
WARNING:  Error fetching data: SocketError: getaddrinfo: nodename nor servname provided, or not known (http://swapna_sony_at_gmail_com:9eea6c960d@modules.locomotivecms.com/specs.4.8.gz)
WARNING:  Error fetching data: SocketError: getaddrinfo: nodename nor servname provided, or not known (http://swapna_sony_at_gmail_com:9eea6c960d@modules.locomotivecms.com/latest_specs.4.8.gz)
```

The gem installation continues after the message and succeeds. I am just wondering what this message means. Is there a config file that contains all server addresses where the installer will go look for the gem and I have somehow got the locomotive address in it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You managed to add a faulty source to your gem system. Check you existing sources

```
gem source --list
```

and remove the faulty one

```
gem source --remove <source>
```

Every time you update your gems the specs are pulled from every source. If this fails you will get the warnings as shown.

See [gem command reference](http://guides.rubygems.org/command-reference/#gem_sources) for additional information.